# How do I make my Rust program communicate to systemd's WatchDog?

Tags: rust, systemd

I've followed this tutorial:
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/start-service-at-boot/
and set everything up.

**Since my problem is exactly this:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298027/restart-systemd-service-when-output-is-no-longer-generated
I've also followed the answers here.

The problem *with the solution*: after 7 hours of runtime, the program stuck. No output generated, systemd didn't restart it.

in my_service.service are both suggested mandatory entries
everything else is correct

```
WatchdogSec=30
Restart=on-watchdog
```

Can I manually make my Rust program communicate with systemd? And if yes - how? I'd love to make it notify systemd at particular lines periodically.

The docs couldn't be more minimal:
https://docs.rs/systemd/latest/systemd/daemon/constant.STATE_WATCHDOG.html
I don't understand a single thing..

Another example crate `libsystemd`, there's 3 search results for WatchDog and this one is the most relevant I guess.
https://docs.rs/libsystemd/latest/libsystemd/daemon/enum.NotifyState.html#variant.Watchdog

IDK how I am able to accomplish anything here. Do I just paste this line anywhere in the program that I want?

`libsystemd::daemon::NotifyState`

how will it know the PID?

In any case: each of those packages has multiple methods, and my program hangs after anywhere from 1-24 hours, trial and error might take weeks.

How can I make my Rust program communicate to the systemd from inside threads, or if impossible - just manually set it up and ensure the WatchDog receives the signal as I want it? What's the line of code for sending a single notification from Rust program to systemd?

As mentioned above the go-to logic is simple: **if no print output, restart the program**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the message somehow. By looking for functions that use the `NotifyState` I found both `systemd::daemon::notify` and `libsystemd::daemon::notify` either of which will do.

For example:

```rust
use systemd::daemon::{notify, STATE_WATCHDOG};
notify(false, [(STATE_WATCHDOG, "1")].iter()).unwrap();
```

Comment: Thank you, implemented it. One thing that concerned me: why didn't systemd reset my program repeatedly, since I did not specify any communication in my Rust file  because I didn't know I should have -  shouldn't it have reset it every 30 seconds? No such thing happened and that made me think I did not need to change anything in the first place.

Comment: Can't reproduce, my busyloop `main` gets killed every 30s with those settings. You do have them under the `[Service]` section, right?

Comment: I think my restart works now, thanks  again for pointing out there must have been more wrong with my settings, I made sure everything is correct, and now it seems - since I'm getting new PID in status, and shorter runtime - restarting is correct! Accepting the answer:)